# Why is Apollo client inserting null values into table for all fields even though values have been specified?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, graphql, sequelize.js, apollo

Here is my Apollo Client code:

```
    mutation  {
  createUser(user_id: 3333, username: "third user", email: "third@email.com", password: "supersecret"){
    user_id
    username
    email
    password
  }
}
```

And below is my typedef schema:

```
const typeDef = gql 
`
    type Query {
        "These are the queries we define in our query type"
        me(user_id: ID): User
    }
    "How to define the structure of user? Below is an object type that does this:"
    type User {
        user_id: ID,
        username: String,
        email: String,
        password: String
    }

    type Mutation {
        createUser(username: String!, email: String!, password: String, user_id: ID): User!
    }
`;
```

Further, I am using sequalize ORM with postgres and my dbIndex is this:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

require('dotenv').config();

const sortDb = new Sequelize(
    `${process.env.DATABASE}`,
    process.env.DATABASE_USER,
    process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    {
      dialect: 'postgres',
    },
);

sortDb
    .authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Connected to SORT MY MIND DB');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error('Unable to connect to DB', err);
    });

// create a DB model which will correspond to 
const account = sortDb.define('account', {
    user_id: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER},
    username: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    passowrd: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    email: {type: Sequelize.STRING}
});

module.exports.account = account;
```

My Query runs perfectly and fetches data from my postgres table. Why isnt mutation running? I see the following error : "Executing (default): INSERT INTO "accounts" ("id","user_id","username","email","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5) RETURNING *;
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: null value in column "password" violates not-null constraint".

This clearly means the Apollo client is trying to insult all null values into my table. How can I fix this?

Comment: Glad you figured it out :) Questions about issues that result from a typographical error are considered off-topic, so let's close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Aah it was a typo in dbIndex!!! "password" Phew :D